# Overriding function parent theme in child theme

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, themes, parent-child

I have some functions to override in my child theme but keep on getting  Cannot redeclare langs_content().

I used quite a few resources to troubleshoot and something that shoud be straight forward I can't work it out

```
<?php
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
//require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/functions.php');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 100 );


if ( ! function_exists( 'langs_content' ) ) {
/*
 * My Awesome function is awesome
 *
 */
        function langs_content( $atts, $content = null ) // shortcode lang
        {     
            $lang = the_lang();     
            extract( shortcode_atts( array(), $atts ) );     
            $langs_content = '';
            if(in_array($lang, $atts))
            { 
                $langs_content .= do_shortcode($content);
            }    
            return $langs_content;
        } 
        add_shortcode('lang', 'langs_content');
}


?>
```

Comment: This can only be done, if they also do it in the original place where the function is

Comment: but, you could recreate your own - like `function custom_langs_content(){//Whatever }add_shortcode('custom_lang', 'custom_langs_content');` and wrap that in `if(function_exists('langs_content')){}` so you are sure that `the_lang()` still works

Answer (score 0):

Really simple ! Remove the shortcode from `init hook` then add your new one ;-)

Like this :

```
/******
* Inside parent functions.php (don't touch this!)
******/
function test_shortcode() {
    return "Hello World from parent theme";
}

add_shortcode('test_shortcode', 'test_shortcode');

/******
* Inside child functions.php
******/
function child_test_shortcode()
{
    return "Hello World from child theme";
}

function remove_parent_theme_shortcodes()
{
    remove_shortcode('test_shortcode');

    // Add our new function with the same shortcode
    add_shortcode('test_shortcode', 'child_test_shortcode');
}

// Remove the shortcode with init hook
add_action('init', 'remove_parent_theme_shortcodes');
```